# disparity of accessing a custom obj's properties in a prototype method when using jquery tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

i'm not quite sure if my approach here is off, or if i just need an elegant way to solve what i'm doing.

i've got a custom Javascript object, called Dude in this example.
Dude has 1 property called 'height' and 1 method defined on its prototype called 'reallyTall'

```
var Dude = function(props) {
    this.height = "tall";
};
Dude.prototype.reallyTall = function() {
    return this.height + " as heck";
};
```

i'm creating an array of Dudes (with just one item in this example), and would like to use jquery.tmpl() to take my Dudes and append them in some fashion to a div in my HTML.
(not caching template for purposes of this simple example)

```
var guy = new Dude();
jQuery.tmpl("<li>${reallyTall}</li>", guy).appendTo('#foo');
```

where #foo is an empty <ul> in the HTML

i'd like to keep my Dude objects 'generic' enough so that if someone does not want to use them with jquery.tmpl, they don't have to....meaning, someone may want to achieve something similar to above, but rather do something like:

```
jQuery("#foo").append('<li>' + guy.reallyTall() + '</li>'));
```

this is where my issue arises - with the value of ***this*** inside of the reallyTall method.

when not using tmpl(), i can access Dude's height property by simply doing

```
this.height
```

but when tmpl() is being used, i'd have to access it like so:

```
this.data.height
```

i could do something like this in the reallyTall method:

```
this.height || this.data.height
```

but that just seems dirty.
i was hoping someone had a better solution to my problem, or can point out if i'm using jquery.tmpl() incorrectly here.

here's a fiddle with my example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/FTF5M/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `${$data.reallyTall()}` in your template.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9CtsV/